# Linq multiple join on same table

Tags: linq, entity, inner-join

how can i write this query in linq?

```
select * from bills as b inner join customer as c1
          On b.shipperID=c1.CustomerID inner join customer c2
          On b.ConsigneeID=c2.CustomerID      
---------------------------
```

I need to have it as below:

```
var result=from p1 in entities.bills
           join p2 in entities.customer on p1.shipperID equals p2.customerID
           join p3 in entities.customer on p1.consigneeID equals p3.customerID
           select p2;
           return resuls.Tolist()
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your SQL you are selecting all so in linq you need to put all objects in your new anonymous type as below.

```
var result = from p1 in entities.bills
             join p2 in entities.customer on p1.shipperID equals p2.customerID
             join p3 in entities.customer on p1.consigneeID equals p3.customerID
             select new 
                 { 
                     Bills = p1,
                     Shippers = p2,
                     Consignees = p3
                 };

             return resuls.Tolist();
```

or if you need them flattened you'll had to project them property by property.

You ought to use navigation properties in LINQ, something like

```
from bills in entities.bills
select new
{
    bills.Shipper
    bills.Consignee
};
```

Comment: Sam,you are the best,I'll be fan of Leeds soccer team:)