# How to set Table Alias in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Given a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
    a.Foo, b.Baa, c.Boo
FROM 
    TableA AS a,
    TableB AS b,
    TableB AS c
WHERE 
    b.Id = a.Col1
    AND c.Id = a.Col3
    AND a.Col42 = "What I Search For"
```

Here I use the same table with two different alias. How can I express that in EF Core?

EDIT:

To make my question clearer, this is the actual SQL query I try to express in EF Core LINQ:

```
SELECT n.id                                   AS "Node ID",
       n.uuid                                 AS "Document ID (UUID)",
       p2.string_value                        AS "Document Name",
       q.local_name                           AS "Data Type",
       u.content_url                          AS "Location",
       u.content_size                         AS "Size (Byte)",
       n.audit_creator                        AS "Creator",
       n.audit_modifier                       AS "Modifier"
FROM alf_node AS n,
     alf_node_properties AS p,
     alf_node_properties AS p1,
     alf_node_properties AS p2,
     alf_namespace AS ns,
     alf_qname AS q,
     alf_content_data AS d,
     alf_content_url AS u
WHERE n.id = p.node_id
  AND ns.id = q.ns_id
  AND p.qname_id = q.id
  AND p.long_value = d.id
  AND d.content_url_id = u.id
  AND p1.node_id = n.id
  AND p1.qname_id IN (SELECT id FROM alf_qname WHERE local_name='content')
  AND p2.node_id = n.id
  AND p2.qname_id IN (SELECT id FROM alf_qname WHERE local_name='filename')
  AND q.local_name IN ('content', 'metadataChunk')
  AND n.uuid = 'a41e6012-8a34-485b-9ff7-c5ae06538bce'
```

The 'Select' part is not the problem.  What I am struggling with is the 'From' and the 'Where' part.

Any idea how to formulate that as a LINQ query for EF Core 7?

Comment: Why would you care what the alias is in an EF Core query?

Comment: @DavidG I need to include the same table twice with different where.

Comment: Why don't you use join twice?https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800667/10193401

Comment: Start writing LINQ query instead of thinking about aliases. EF Core will create appropriate aliases automatically.

Comment: Short answer, post this query to ChatGPT - it will convert it almost close to expectations. Long answer - LINQ queries are built form classes and their navigation properties, so show these classes.

Comment: Also, sometimes it's better/easier to just run raw SQL queries.